# Chartjs chart is not displaying instead view displays only json data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I'm trying to load the chart.js line chart in my asp.net view but the view is showing only json data.

The page not even displaying the layout page, just displaying the json data returned from the controller.

Below is my view and the controller and json returned.

my view

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "LoadLineChart";
}

<h2>LoadLineChart</h2>
<div>
<label>Multi Bar Chart</label>
<canvas id="LineChart" width="400" height="150"></canvas>
</div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/Chart.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/LoadLineChart",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var c = document.getElementById("LineChart");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: data
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('some thing wrong try again...')
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

my controller

```
public JsonResult LoadLineChart()
    {
        string[] chartcolors = {
             "rgb(255, 99, 132)",//red
             "rgb(54, 162, 235)",//blue
             "rgb(153, 102, 255)",//purple
             "rgb(255, 159, 64)",//orange
             "rgb(255, 205, 86)",//yellow
             "rgb(75, 192, 192)",//green           
             "rgb(231,233,237)"//grey
        };

        ChartData cd = new ChartData();
        DataTable dat = cd.GetSIMCardData();
        Chart _chart = new Chart();
        _chart.labels = dat.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("month") + "-" + r.Field<string>("year")).ToArray();
        _chart.datasets = new List<Datasets>();
        List<Datasets> _dataSet = new List<Datasets>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var bgcolor = Enumerable.Repeat(chartcolors[i], dat.Rows.Count).ToArray();
            _dataSet.Add(new Datasets()
            {
                label = dat.Columns[i].ColumnName,
                data = dat.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>(dat.Columns[i])).ToArray(),
                backgroundColor = bgcolor,
                borderColor = bgcolor,
                borderWidth = "1"
            });
            _chart.datasets = _dataSet;
        }


        return Json(_chart, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

//json data displaying in the view

```
{"labels":["November-2016","December-2016","January-2017","February-
2017","March-2017","April-2017","May-2017","June-2017","July-2017","August-
2017","September-2017","October-2017"],
"datasets":[{"label":"NormalSim",
"backgroundColor":["rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 
132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 
99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 
132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)"],"borderColor":["rgb(255, 99, 
132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 
99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 
132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 
99, 132)"],
"borderWidth":"1",
"data": [10702400,10456635,10236438,10037215,10051764,9877641,9642252,
9519984,9360297, 9337899,9229813,9202321]}]}
```

Comment: Some where (in code you have not shown) you making a redirect to that method.

Comment: Hi stephen, added the controller code